# Data validation list is being ignored

Tags: excel, vba, list, validation

I have the following situation: on one cell, I have a Data - validation - list which should restrict the user to selecting only items from that list. 
On the same cell I have on change triggers in VBA, so when the cell value is changed it also records the change into a Changelog sheet (it uses undo to get the previous value, and undo again to redo the change to the new value)

The problem is, right now, the Data - validation - list is being totally ignored, so the users can put what ever they want in that specific cell, even though I have "Show error" checked.

Is there a way to enforce the list validation, so the users can only select items from the list and not enter whatever they want? Or to trigger the on cell change event after the validation?

Maybe someone can clarify the order in which these things happen.

Comment: Does it work properly if you temporarily disable the VBA?

Comment: (I am assuming that you have already taken into account the potential Stack Overflow caused by the `Application.Undo` changing the cell value, which calls the `Worksheet_Change` event, triggering the `Application.Undo` command again, et cetera?)

Comment: Help us to help you; **post your current code**.

Comment: Hi, I would like to share a few more details: The list source for the initial cell was a named range that had a few empty cells. I tested  the same scenario for a cell with exactly the same properties, except the list was a fixed address ( "A2:A30"), and the validation worked as expected. Could the empty rows at the end of the named range disable the validation? also i was trying to put "qwe" in the cell, i would expect "" to be accepted, not "qwe".

Comment: I updated the source of the list to a simple address and now the validation works as expected, but this complicated the Worksheet_Change event. See, if I click on "Cancel" for the message "This value doesn't match the validations restrictions", i would want to cancel the Worksheet_Change event, because as Chronicidial said, Excel already undid the change, but if i use If Target.Validation.Value=false, the value has already been reverted to the old one. How can i cancel the Worksheet_Change event in this case?

Comment: @DumitruDaniel First, you can always [edit] your post, instead of using excessive comments.  Second - you can't.  While you can `Exit Sub` to cancel the `Worksheet_Change` event, it has no way to tell whether the cell validation failed or not.  You would have to remove the "Show Error", and use `Target.Validation.Value` to run your own validation check instead.  Or, store duplicates of the old values somewhere else (a "Very Hidden" worksheet?), and use those instead of using `Application.Undo` to get the previous value

Answer (score 0):

I recently worked on range.Validation.type=xlValidateList and wanted to prevent paste and cut and disallow typing wrong characters into the cell containing the dropdown list(and making it possible to type characters that match an entry in the list and show that entry).

While working on the last thing that was not OK (cutting a dropdown and pasting it into another cell already containing a dropdown) I discoverd an EASY way of prohibiting paste and cut for Data Validation Lists that do allow further processing depending on what has been entered,

the following code has to be on the worksheet module.
It prevents the user from destroying Data Validation on cells and because of that using Application.Undo to revert to the state before pasting or cutting is no longer needed.

I don't know if it makes a difference but I protected the sheet and unlocked the cells the user may alter.

```
Private Function HasValidation(ByVal rng As Range) As Boolean
' See:       https://superuser.com/questions/870926/restrict-paste-into-dropdown-cells-in-excel
' Returns True if every cell in Range r uses Data Validation
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim rngType: rngType = rng.Validation.Type
    HasValidation = (Err.number = 0)
End Function

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
' Switch DragAndDrop on/off on a range containing DataValidation
    Dim modeCutCopy: modeCutCopy = Application.CutCopyMode
    Dim usesValidation: usesValidation = HasValidation(Target)
    If ((usesValidation = True) And (modeCutCopy <> 0)) Then Application.CutCopyMode = False     ' MUST reset to avoid copying / cutting xlValidateList into another xlValidateList
    ' Turn DragAnddDrop on/off depending on if a cell uses Validation or not
    If (usesValidation = Application.CellDragAndDrop) Then Application.CellDragAndDrop = (Not usesValidation)

GoTo SKIP
    ' Don't allow DragAndDrop if Target intersects with specified ranges
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Worksheets("Evenementen").Range("Oordeel", "Waardering")
    Dim rngIntersect As Range
    Set rngIntersect = Application.Intersect(Target, myRange)
    Application.CellDragAndDrop = (rngIntersect Is Nothing)
''    CheckInputValidationList(Target)          ' Sophisticated testing and actions depending on the selection made
''    CheckInputValidationList(Target, myRange) ' Sophisticated testing and actions depending on the selection made for specific ranges

SKIP:

Debug.Print "SelectionChange  " & Target.Address & "    usesValidation=" & usesValidation & "   cellDragAndDrop=" & Application.CellDragAndDrop
End Sub
```

In this case there are two named ranges containing (different) Data Validation Lists.
As soon as the user clicks on a cell a check will be performed if that cell uses data validation.
If so cut and paste will be turned off and CutCopyMode will be cleared until the user selects another cell.

Important is to retrieve the current CutCopyMode BEFORE any VBA-code will be executed that changes something as VBA will automatically change CutCopyMode from xlCut or xlCopy into 0 when something changes.
That initiall state is required to avoid pasting a dropdownlist over another.

The Worksheet_SelectionChange subroutine contains  SKIPPED code that does something similar if a user accesses a cell in one of two ranges.
It also contains the (turned into comment) code to perform additional actions when the user selects a cell. That code might also be put in worksheet_Change